# Why the report errors out when evaluating a formula that equals zero?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have this formula field:

```
global numbervar TotDiff;

WhilePrintingRecords;

if {@QuantExceding} <> 0 then
    TotDiff := TotDiff + ABS({@QuantExceding})
else
    TotDiff := TotDiff
```

Initially, the if clause was not there, so I thought it was `ABS` erroring out when passed 0. Then I see that whatever I do with `QuantExceding`, when it equals 0, the reports errors out and highlights the first line of the if or whatever the line that invokes `QuantExceding`

Any ideas ?

Comment: why do you have the if statement, just use TotDiff := TotDiff + ABS({@QuantExceding})

Comment: Please re-read the text below the code. The formula errors out on ABS({@QuantExceding})  anyways.

Comment: QuantExceding might be returning NULL value

Comment: No it's not, it's 0. At least, that what's the debugger shows me. It's all written down in the question. Even when I do a null check, the line that does the null check errors out.

Comment: what about if you place QuantExceding formula in your details section, does it only return numeric values?

Comment: what about this TotDiff := TotDiff + ABS(tonumber({@QuantExceding}))

Comment: Nope. As soon as I invoke @QuantExceding in some form, report errors out and highlights the line invoking it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83981/discussion-between-cojimarmiami-and-francis-ducharme).

Answer (score 0):

change formula like this and make sure the {@QuantExceding} is evaluating first:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
EvaluateAfter({@QuantExceding});
global numbervar TotDiff;

if {@QuantExceding} <> 0 then
    TotDiff := TotDiff + ABS({@QuantExceding})
else
    TotDiff := TotDiff
```